# Check if a function takes an array or single valued input

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a function that takes an array and another function as an input. The only thing I know about the supplied function though is that it either

1. takes a single number argument and returns a new number or
2. takes an array of numbers and returns a new array of numbers.

In my function, I want to check whether it's the first or second case to determine whether or not to call the supplied function with `Array.prototype.map()`.

So with these two functions...

```
var unknownFunction = function( unknownInput ) {
  //Does stuff with input

  //returns number or array of numbers...
  return someValueOrValues
}
```

and

```
var mainFunction = function( anArray, preFunction ){

  // SOME CODE TO CHECK IF ARG NEEDS TO BE NUMBER OR ARRAY
  // ...
  // ...

    **ANSWER WOULD FIT HERE**


  if( argIsNumber === true ){
    // function takes NUMBER
    anArray = anArray.map( preFunction )
  }else{
    // function takes ARRAY
    anArray = preFunction(anArray)
  }

  // DO STUFF WITH ARRAY AFTER USER FUNCTION HAS MADE IT'S MODIFICATIONS
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...

  return anArray;
}
```

is there any way to poke inside the first function to figure out how best to call it?

Comment: You could put it in a try/catch.  Trying to access an array when it's just a number would trip the error...

Comment: This isn't possible. You cannot tell (in general) whether a function accepts an array or a number without running the function, and even then you cannot be sure. This is a subclass of [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and there is no solution for it.

Comment: @meagar is right, but you may use Function.prototype.toString that in most browsers returns function source code + some conventions on parameter names e.g. if first parameters is named array - not fool prof but may work

Comment: @meagar Consider `function unknownFunction(unknownInput) { if (Math.random() > 0.5) { treat unknownInput as a number } else { treat unknownInput as an array } }`. This function changes its behavior each time you call it! It's worse than the Halting Problem because the behavior changes even for the same input!

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I'm very aware. That's not "worse" than the Halting Problem, it is **the same problem**. I specifically said "**and even then you cannot be sure**" to cover that case.  The classic example of why the Halting Problem is hard takes your exact logic and simply substitutes `return/don't return` for `treat like number`/`treat like array`.

Comment: @RaymondChen can you explain your comment with the example function more? I'm not understanding the relevance. My `unknownFunction` isn't varying in the way it treats it's input, but my `mainFunction` should be able to handle either `unkFuncA` or `unkFuncB` which return a single value and an array, respectively.

Comment: The function I gave sometimes treats its input as a number and sometimes treats its input as an array, in an unpredictable way. It is therefore impossible to answer the question "Does this function treat the input as a number?" because the answer is "Maybe."

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh, I see what you mean - thanks for clarifying. It seems like that would complicate things, but I would expect that function to on, a practical level, to gracefully accept either/or or risk hitting an error 50% of the time. If the function accepts either than it doesn't matter how it's called. On a more general, computer-science-y level, I get where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the try-catch approach but test the actual functions, and if one fails to try the next one.

Let's say these are your functions that are passed in as your unknow function. They each only modify a number by adding 1 to it.

```
function onlyTakesNumber(num) {
    return num + 1;
}

function onlyTakesArray(arr) {
    return arr.map(num => num + 1);
}
```

Now, here is your main function. The reason for the additional map inside of the `try` is to test to make sure you didn't get a string back if an array was passed to the `onlyTakesNumber` function. The additional test map will again reveal if the code needs to hop into the catch.

```
var mainFunction = function (anArray, preFunction) {

    try {
        // the map on the end checks to make sure you did not get a string back
        anArray = preFunction(anArray).map(test => test);
    }
    catch (e) {
        anArray = anArray.map(preFunction);
    }

    // Do whatever else with anArray

    return anArray;
};


console.log(mainFunction([1, 2, 3], onlyTakesArray)); // [2, 3, 4]
console.log(mainFunction([7, 8, 9], onlyTakesNumber)); // [8, 9, 10]
```

**Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnuep54p/2/) you can test this on**

Comment: Horrible solution. This is known as an anti-pattern!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, your answer doesn't even address an actual problem the OP has "The only thing I know about the supplied function though is that it either...". He does not have access to the functions to decide whether or not to do this: `func.type = "number";`, which your answer hinges upon.

Comment: You don't need to have access to that functions to being able to add a property to the function object.

Comment: Correct, but he doesn't know what value to add to the property since he can't read the function to know what it's supposed to accept, number or array.

Comment: BTW, my answer does solve the actual problem. Yours too. The problem with yours is that it has a high impact in performance and it's a very very bad coding practice. It's not about "yours vs mine"... When I added the comment to your answer I did independently of my answer: this is a bad solution.

Comment: Ermm... When I suggested the OP to add a `type` property I wasn't thinking about evaluating the function in real-time. You would add the `type` property in the same file where the function is defined, because who coded that function already knows what will be the input parameter *expected* type...

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I'm not trying to make this about yours vs mine either. But I think where we have a misunderstanding is that from what I read, and my understanding of the question, the OP does not have access to the *source code* of the unknown functions. For example, it could be a 3rd party library, or an import from a library, etc. For sure, if he has access to the source code of those functions, I would agree that your solution would solve that problem much better, but my answer is on the assumption that the OP does not have that access as stated in the question.

Comment: I believe that OP's issue is an XY problem... OP asked for an answer without explaining what's the underlying problem

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language, function's input parameters have type once some calls it with some *argument*.

One elegant and possible approach is adding a property to the whole given function to hint the input parameter type:

```
var func = function() {};
func.type = "number"; // a function decorator

var mainFunction = function(anArray, inputFunc) {
    if(typeof inputFunc != "function") {
         throw Error("Please supply a function as 'inputFunc'!");
    } 

    switch(inputFunc.type) {
        case "number":
           return anArray.map(preFunction);

        case "array": 
           return preFunction(anArray);

        default:
           throw Error("Type not supported");
    }
};

mainFunction([1,2,3], func);
```

When you work with dynamically-typed languages you need to think about coding using [*convention over configuration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and/or using [*duck typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Type safety provided by strongly-typed languages is replaced by a good documentation.

For example:

> Provide a function as second parameter with a `type` property to tell
>   the `mainFunction` what's the expected type of the predicate
>   function.

Comment: It would be nice to know why I got a downvote and know if my approach is broken somehow..

Comment: Matias, unfortunately @kevbot 's observation (on the other answer) is accurate -- I don't have access to the functions to decide if a type property is added. Nevertheless, I think this is a pretty ingenious solution and should the try/catch solution cause start to cause issues, I'll likely try to find a way to make this approach work. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveLadavich As I said to the other answerer on comment, you don't need to have access to the functions to add a type property to the function object. It's just that who defines those functions should add the whole property. In AngularJS, this pattern is used to define *explicit injections*: `controller.$inject = ["$scope"]`, and it's a common pattern now with *decorators*.

Comment: @SteveLadavich It's up to you to go with the try-catch route. BTW, as I said too, it's an anti-pattern and it's the easiest but worst solution to solve your issue...

Comment: @SteveLadavich BTW if you don't even have access to functions' source code, it's not something you've said in your question and that detail should be added there. For those who have access to the entire source code base, my answer will work fine, and since StackOverflow answers aren't just for the OP (you), there's nothing wrong with leaving my answer for future visitors (or even you, if you can go with this approach)! :)

Answer (score -1):

The shortest answer is: "you can't".

Comment: the shortest comment is "why?".

Comment: You can't!
No external function can access another function's arguments unless hardcoded by you to return them.

Comment: @ocanal, every yesterday JavaScript newcomer knows that - asking if there is some sort of a hack - is not prohibited - but the answer will forever be:  no you cannot - and that's because you are not allowed to - it's a security issue.